# How do you calculate a total from multiple Component values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React and I've been struggling to find a solution that works. I am trying to display a total from multiple number inputs.
I tried passing a function as prop and calling it to retrieve the values, but that seems to reset the Child Component's state to **initial**.

If passing a function as prop is the intended solution, can I somehow prevent **input** from being reset? I assume it has something to do with rerendering the component, but it doesn't happen consistently.

Below is some simplified code of the problem I have. I want the state **total** to sum up all **input** states in the UserInput components. **Key** will be the label and is predetermined, so a switch statement is applicable.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import UserInput from "./UserInput";

function App() {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{total}</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <UserInput key="Input1" initial={12} />
            <UserInput key="Input2" initial={15} />
            <UserInput key="Input3" initial={9} />
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

UserInput.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function UserInput({ initial }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(initial);
  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      let value = parseInt(event.target.value);
      if (isNaN(value)) return;
      setInput(value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <td>
      <input type="number" defaultValue={initial} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
      <p>{input}</p>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html (create an array of values in your App component, pass down the value and a setter function to each input)

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js (note that you can simply edit `initialState` and everything else is changing accordingly)

Comment: @ChrisG thank you, works wonderfully! I definitely approached this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

So in your case what is happening is that whenever you try to sum up all the inputs value the parent gets rerender with all its child resetting the state of the child i.e UserInput. React has this default behavior of resetting all corresponding children on parent set State. So you need to take your child's component state to parent. So you can add logic there, to sum up all the values coming from a child.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserInput from "./UserInput";

export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInput] = useState([
    { key: "Input1", initial: 12 },
    { key: "Input2", initial: 15 },
    { key: "Input3", initial: 9 }
  ]);

  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const arrSum = inputs.reduce((acc, { initial }) => acc + initial, 0);
    setTotal(arrSum);
  }, [inputs]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{total} adasdsa</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {inputs.map(({ key, initial }, index) => (
              <UserInput
                key={key}
                initial={initial}
                setInitial={(val) => {
                  const temp = [...inputs];
                  temp[index].initial = val;
                  setInput(temp);
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and in your child you will simply do this.

```
export default function UserInput({ initial, setInitial }) {
  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      let value = parseInt(event.target.value);
      if (isNaN(value)) return;
      setInitial(value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <td>
      <input type="number" defaultValue={initial} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
      <p>{initial}</p>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Adding sandbox link so you can check https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-thompson-cwycko?file=/src/UserInput.jsx:0-382

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function UserInput({ initial, value, onChange, name }) {
  return (
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        defaultValue={initial}
        onKeyDown={(e) => onChange(e, name)}
      />
      <p>{value}</p>
    </td>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    Input1: 0,
    Input2: 0,
    Input3: 0
  });
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = ({ key, target: { value } }, name) => {
    if (key === "Enter") {
      if (isNaN(value)) return;
      setValues((state) => ({ ...state, [name]: +value }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(Object.values(values).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
  }, [values]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{total}</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <UserInput
              name="Input1"
              value={values["Input1"]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              key="Input1"
              initial={12}
            />
            <UserInput
              name="Input2"
              value={values["Input2"]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              key="Input2"
              initial={15}
            />
            <UserInput
              name="Input3"
              value={values["Input3"]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              key="Input3"
              initial={9}
            />
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).